# Can you use #define to change a #include?

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

Is it possible to change the library included using `#include <foo>` or `#include "foo"` to something different during prepossessing so it would instead act as a different library, for example `#include <bar>`?  I have a library that is not working with the current `#include` statement in just one context, but works fine elsewhere, so I don't want to change it directly.  Would it be possible to use `#define` to fix this?

Comment: #ifdef foo #define bar #ifndef foo #define foobar #endif

Comment: yes, you could do a #ifdef SOMEVAR and then #include <foo> #else #include <bar>

Comment: You can also do `#define FILENAME "something"` (where the definition is based on other macros) followed by `#include FILENAME` to include a different file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to do this.  The simpler, more obvious way:

```
#define INCLUDE_FOO

// ...

#ifdef INCLUDE_FOO
#include <foo>
#else
#include <bar>
#endif
```

And the shorter, but finickier way:

```
#define FOO_HEADER "foo"

// ...

#include FOO_HEADER
```

You have to be careful if you use the second way, because the C standard does not fully define the behavior of `#include` followed by anything which is not either `"..."` or `<...>`.  It says that the "anything which is not..." is fully macro-expanded, *not* applying the special tokenization rules for `#include` lines (e.g. `<foo.h>` is five tokens, not one) 
and then something implementation-defined happens.

If the result of full macro expansion is a single string literal token, all implementations I know about will do what you expect, i.e. they will treat that as if `#include "..."` had been written, where the `...` is the contents of the string literal.  (However, the behavior of backslashes within the string literal may be not as you expect.  Use only forward slashes for directory separators; that works reliably on Windows as well as elsewhere.)

If the result of full macro expansion is *anything else*, the behavior is unpredictable and differs not only between implementations, but between point releases of the *same* implementation.  Avoid.

Addendum: If an `#include` line is written in one of the two typical formats to begin with...

```
#include "foo"
#include <foo>
```

... then macro expansion does not happen and cannot be forced to happen.  This means you are probably up a creek wrt your desire to avoid changing the third-party header with the problem.

Comment: This is an interesting way of doing things.  I guess you could add some `#ifndef` logic to make it slightly better so at least something is defined for the `#include`.  Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 3):

Basically in your cpp file you can define a variable that toggles the behaviour of the include file:

So in a.cpp

```
#define BAR
#include "myHeader.h"
```

in "myheader.h:"

```
#ifdef BAR
#include <bar>
#else
#include <foo>
#endif
```

There is a good [GOTW](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/032.htm) article on other ways you can use preprocessor macros to toggle behaviour

Comment: That works.  Thank you.  Just wondering, is there a way to do this without having to change the library at all?

Comment: I don't think so, I'm just racking my brains to see if you #undef it I think not because you are controlling the behaviour of the header file so the file has to know how to toggle the header files it needs to include

Comment: I was thinking if you could #undef #include but that is not allowed and even if it was it doesn't change what it includes, so I think you can't do this without modifying the header